# Чередование корней у глаголов несовершенного вида

Tags: глаголы, однокоренные-слова, корень-слова

Подметил закономерность, что многие глаголы можно классифицировать по корням:

```
лег/леж  - возлегать, возлежать
род/рожд - рожать, рождать
ес/ед    - есть, едать
бег/беж  - бегать, бежать
```

Как называется это явление, почему оно проявляется и как много глаголов охватывает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Как называется это явление, почему оно проявляется и как много глаголов охватывает?*

- лег/леж  - возлегать, возлежать, бег/беж  - бегать, бежать - первая
  палатализация.
- род/рожд - рожать, рождать - вариация
  древнерусского/старославянского.
- ес/ед - есть, едать - отпадение Д (*ědti; dt > tt > ст, то же самое в "вести") в одной из форм.

Сомневаюсь, что - с учетом словообразовательных вариантов - кто-то их считал, незачем вроде.

Comment: Вот с 15-ю глаголами движения лингвисты заморочились - нашли причину существования сразу двух корневых форм. А с другими глаголами, вы не заморачиваетесь, просто её констатируете и показываете этимологию.  Смысл же моего вопроса как раз в том, чтобы найти причину существования обоих форм (другими словами, найти разницу между этими формами и определить функции этих глаголов в РЯ), не только у 15-и глаголов движения, но и у остальных глаголов. Заодно и посчитать и разбить на другие классы глаголов.

Comment: Да уж где нам до аналитики. Про палатализацию мы знаем с рождения, живем на расслабоне. Не помогаем бедным гражданам вообще ни разу, как они только терпят нас тунеядцев